# Download and Display Map for Offline View

Tags: flutter

I have been using map_view plugin to display map in flutter. I want to download specified area for offline view. There is no in build method to download map. How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find this too, the only solution that I found - create mbtiles by your own,
I am using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) to show map

And for map creation I using [GMapCatcher](https://github.com/heldersepu/GMapCatcher)

And for creation .mbtiles I using [this util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/)

I think this can help you :)

If you already found another way to create offline maps in flutter, please can you share?